# Quick way to determine the number of k-length paths from A to B in a dense complete graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

Given a complete dense graph (over 250.000 nodes) , what is the quickest way to determine the number of k-length paths from node A to B ?

Comment: In a [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of `N` nodes, the number of k-length paths from node `A` to `B` is `(N-2)*(N-3)^(k-2)` (assuming no self-edges, nodes `A` and `B` can only appear as endpoints of the path, and `k > 1`).

Comment: If you're uncertain as to why this works I can post an explanation. Also you'll notice that I've made a lot of assumptions. If any of these are incorrect, please correct them.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is an old post, but I had the exact same question and could not find the answer.

I like to think of this problem as a "permutation without repetition", as the order of the nodes visited matters (permutation) and we aren't backtracking (no repetitions).  The number of permutations without repetition is: n!/(n-r)!

For a complete graph with N nodes, there are N - 2 remaining nodes to choose from when creating a path between a given A and B.  To create a path of length K, K-1 nodes must be chosen from the remaining nodes after A and B are excluded.  Therefore, in this context, n = N - 2, and r = k - 1.

Plugging into the above formula yields:

(N-2)!/(N-K-1)!

Example: for N = 5, with nodes 0,1,2,3,4 the following paths are possible from 0 to 1:

0 1

0 2 1

0 2 3 1

0 2 3 4 1

0 2 4 1

0 2 4 3 1

0 3 1

0 3 2 1

0 3 2 4 1

0 3 4 1

0 3 4 2 1

0 4 1

0 4 2 1

0 4 2 3 1

0 4 3 1

0 4 3 2 1

This yields 1 path of length 1, 3 paths of length 2, 6 paths of length 3, and 6 paths of length 4.

This appears to work for any N>=2 and K<=N-1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basically dynamic programming: For each node Y and path length k, you can compute the number of paths from A to Y of length k if you know the number of paths from A to X of path length k-1 for all nodes X. Total complexity is O(KV), where K is the total path length you are trying to compute for and V is the number of vertices.